# Azure EndPoint Monitoring - Memory Usage

Tags: azure

Is there a way to create an End Point for a Azure virtual machine to monitor memory usage?

We are looking to view memory usage for each 24 hour period?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really an *endpoint* to create (endpoints in Azure are ports; I guess you could create an Input Endpoint which is public-facing, and place a service there that you can call externally). But... there are several options for adding monitoring:

- [MetricsHub](http://www.metricshub.com) (recently acquired by Microsoft).
- [NewRelic](http://newrelic.com)
- [AppDynamics](http://appdynamics.com)

With Virtual Machines, you'd install an agent on your VMs.

Each of these is available in the Azure Store:
[image]

You'll find that each is focused on different aspects. MetricsHub is likely best for your case, looking at all of your Azure-specific resources. NewRelic adds in app-level details, and AppDynamics focuses on app-level details (specifically Java and .net apps, where it can inspect the runtime).